# Loading the dataset in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to download and load a dataset in jupyter notebook but I got an issue, here is the code  :

```
import os
import tarfile
from six.moves import urllib

DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml/master/"
HOUSING_PATH = os.path.join("datasets", "housing")
HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/housing/housing.tgz"

def fetch_housing_data(housing_url=HOUSING_URL, housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
    if not os.path.isdir(housing_path):
        os.makedirs(housing_path)
    tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url, tgz_path)
    housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path)
    housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)
    housing_tgz.close()

import pandas as pd
def load_housing_data(housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
    csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.csv")
    return pd.read_csv(csv_path)

housing = load_housing_data()
housing.head()
```

After running the above code I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-6a9011700846> in <module>
----> 1 housing = load_housing_data()
      2 housing.head()

<ipython-input-4-4d0bff7b3608> in load_housing_data(housing_path)
      2 def load_housing_data(housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
      3     csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.csv")
----> 4     return pd.read_csv(csv_path)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, doublequote, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    676                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    677 
--> 678         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    679 
    680     parser_f.__name__ = name

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    438 
    439     # Create the parser.
--> 440     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    441 
    442     if chunksize or iterator:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    785             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    786 
--> 787         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    788 
    789     def close(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1012     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
   1013         if engine == 'c':
-> 1014             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1015         else:
   1016             if engine == 'python':

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1706         kwds['usecols'] = self.usecols
   1707 
-> 1708         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1709 
   1710         passed_names = self.names is None

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: File b'datasets/housing/housing.csv' does not exist
```

I tried to download the data manually and added the .CSV file in the same folder, it works fine with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.read_csv('housing.csv', delimiter = ',')
```

My question is about what is wrong with the first coding?, I would be very appreciated if anyone can explain that. By the way, I am using Mac 10.14.

Note: That coding is an example from the book of "Hands on Machine Learning with Scikit Learn and Tensorflow"

Comment: If you run `os.listdir()` are you able to see the `datasets` folder?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please write your code out in plain text in your post? If you're having a problem with running some code, we usually like to try to run the same code ourselves to see if there's an obvious issue. Please also try to be explicit in what went wrong, and what behavior you were expecting. Check out the [guidelines for how to ask good questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Happy trails!

Comment: Please include the code as text instead of linking to a picture.

Comment: @mkrieger1 sorry for that, I added the code as text.

Comment: @JordanSinger thanks for your advice and sorry about that, I added the code as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`def fetch_housing_data()` is not called, so there is no directory or downloaded files. 
you need to call `fetch_housing_data()` in the body of `def load_housing_data`

like this:

```
def load_housing_data(housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
    # missing function call to fetch the data
    fetch_housing_data()
    csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.csv")
    return pd.read_csv(csv_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model


# In[4]:


df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\nandika\Desktop\homeprices.csv") # the r is required
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer